# Frontend Form 404 action

Tags: magento-1.7, forms

Using Magento 1.7 and I've created a simple frontend form, however, when I go to test and submit the form it returns the 404 page, though I'm really not sure why.

Here is my code structure:

```
|-Vendor
|-----Module
|---------Block
|-------------Form.php
|---------controllers
|-------------IndexController.php
|---------etc
|-------------config.xml
```

Form.php:

```
<?php
    class Vendor_Module_Block_Form extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
        public function getFormAction()
        {
            return $this->getUrl('module/index/post');
        }
    }
```

IndexController.php

```
<?php
    class Vendor_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
    {
        public function postAction()
        {
            //custom form stuff
        }
    }
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <module>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Vendor_Module before="Mage_Contacts">Vendor_Module</Vendor_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <module>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Block</class>
            </module>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

I've checked in admin and can see that it is enabled, I've added a Helper/Data.php file as suggested in another SO post. I've cleared cache and reindexed but still, it doesn't work.

Any ideas or anything clearly wrong that I've missed?

Comment: There might be an issue with your form action URL. Please check it again.

Comment: @Piyush because I want custom validation stuff :)

Comment: @DineshYadav how can I checkl more than I already have?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs if overriding controller is necessary then check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134010/20064

Comment: @Piyush the only thing that was new was the observer, but that's not needed because I don't intend to prevent anything :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are extending/rewriting the contacts index controller, so you should use `contacts/index/postcustom` in your form action instead of `module/index/post`. And update your codes with the below guide.

In your ***IndexController.php***, require the `Mage_Contacts_IndexController` file. See version below:

```
<?php

require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Contacts').DS.'IndexController.php');

class Vendor_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController {
    public function postcustomAction()
    {
        //custom form stuff
    }
}
```

And in your ***config.xml***, update the `frontend>routers...` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
      <routers>
        <contacts>
          <args>
            <modules>
              <vendor_module_contacts before="Mage_Contacts">Vendor_Module</vendor_module_contacts>
            </modules>
          </args>
        </contacts>
      </routers>
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Make sure that you flush your cache to see the new changes.

Comment: You are extending the contactss router, so you should use `contacts/index/post` in your form action instead of `module/index/post`.

Comment: Notice the `contacts` and  `before="Mage_Contacts"` in your `config.xml` file. It tells Magento to use yours first before the actual class from `contacts` module.

Comment: Can you compress your module and attach it here. Just the module in `app/code` so we can better investigate what's the issue. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69008/discussion-between-ner-and-thisguyhastwothumbs).